# Having Two Columns With Primary Keys Not Two Columns With One Primary Keys

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

In A Table I want to have two columns with primary keys(that avoid insert value if each of two columns are duplicate) but not two columns with one primary key together(this avoid insert value if both of column are duplicate)

For Example :

column1:a,b,c

column2:1,2,3

in this table i dont want to insert (column1:a and column2:4) or(column1:d and column2:3)

Comment: Use a clustered key on PRIkey1 and priKEY2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an index for the second column with UNIQUE property set.

Comment: Just replace TABLENAME and COLUMNNAME by whatever you need.    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TABLENAME ON dbo.TABLENAME
 (
 COLUMNNAME
 )

Answer (score 7):

You can only have one primary key, that's kind of the point. Add a unique constraint on the other column?

Answer (score 1):

you cant. A table can have have only one primary key. 
Consider using two unique indexes.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index1 ON Table(column1);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index2 ON Table(column2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may set only one Primary key. For the next you may create unique keys or combine a unique combinational keys (Composite Keys).

Answer (score 0):

Use one primary key and one unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key in column1 for instance, and a unique index on columnb.